# Setting CPU frequency for an i5-430M

Tags: xubuntu, cpufreq

I run Xubuntu 18.04 on a Toshiba L505 laptop with an i5-430M CPU. Is there any way I can limit the maximum CPU frequency? This can easily be done in Windows 7 (by limiting CPU to e.g. 70%). Also, there is no "/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/".

Comment: If you don't have that directory, then either your processor doesn't support CPU frequency scaling or it is disabled in BIOS. Does your computer have the new location? `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0` , which should have legacy links from the old locations.

Comment: @DougSmythies That directory is empty. I looked into the BIOS (there are no options to set CPU frequency).

Answer (score 0):

You could try to install the Cpufreq extension (https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1082/cpufreq/) which should give you a gui to set the cpu limits.

Comment: I am not using Gnome.